# How to change hours, minutes, and seconds separately using a JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, time, jspinner

Could someone please advise how I can show a time of format `hh:mm:ss,msms` in a `JSpinner`. How can I set the spinner to allow independent adjustment of the hours, minutes, and seconds?

```
Start_time_jSpinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
```

Comment: See [*How to Use Spinners*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest would probably be to create 3 separate spinners, where the first one has values 0-23 (for hours) and the other 2 have values 0-59 (for minutes and seconds).

Refer to the API documentation here... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html

Or there is a tutorial here which will probably help you... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

You should attempt to implement your spinners, and if you still need assistance, post some code here and we'll be able to better help.